# Run c++ program multiple times with different files as input

Tags: macos, shell, unix

I've got an executable that I need to run from the command line multiple times with a different file as input each time the program is run. I'm using UNIX and the files are stored in a directory called `tests` in the same directory as the program.

I want to do something similar to the following:

`for i in {1..50} ; do ./program ; done`

except with a different file as input each time it runs. So, iterating over all of the files in the directory `tests` would be what I want to do, correct?

Not quite sure how/what to google for this (already have tried though).

Any insight? Thanks!

Comment: `for file in tests/*; do ./program "$file"; done`?

Comment: Yeah wow, thanks. I realized that I could have googled my question but the correct words just weren't coming to mind. Appreciate it. Answer it if you'd like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do this.  One very reasonable approach is to rewrite the program to be more unix-like and accept multiple filenames as trailing arguments so that you can simply invoke:

```
./program tests/*
```

Without changing the program, you can also do any of (in decreasing order of preferrance):

```
find tests -exec ./program {} \;
for f in tests/*; do ./program "$f"; done
ls -f tests | while read f; do ./program tests/"$f"; done  # Use caution
```

Note that many will argue against ever using `ls` as is done in the 3rd example above, since it can lead to incorrect behavior if any files contain a newline in their name, but it behaves better than the glob if the directory contains many files.  You can avoid those concerns by using `find`.